# How to add a legend without plot rescaling?

Tags: matlab

I'm using a figure having 4 subplots. For the first plot I need to add a legend. But when I add it, the first plot is rescaled.

I don't want to specify location using `set()` due to the fact the sublots' number may change on the same figure.

This is how I add the legend:

```
legend('Constant','Adaptive','Location','northoutside','Orientation','horizontal');
```

This is my current figure.
[image]

Comment: I do not understand, can you also show us a plot of what happens when you add this legend? (And please use minimal working examples.)

Comment: @flawr all 4 subplots should be the same size, when the legend is added the top subplot is modified to fit the legend.

Comment: Ok, Well a primitive solution would be just adding fifth subplot, and calling that one before adding the legend.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add legend outside of axes without rescaling in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602571/add-legend-outside-of-axes-without-rescaling-in-matlab)

Comment: Well, simple solution is to drag/drop your legend out of the axes with your mouse. By doing so, the axes gets its initial size back.

Comment: @macduf Thank you! This is the solution that fits my purpose. Can you please add it as an answer in order to accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By **dragging/dropping the legend** with your mouse out of the axes, Matlab sets the axes location back to its initial position.

Even if the resize is automatic after the drag&drop, I've not found a solution that does not make use of the mouse though. For a single or a few plots, this trick will make it I think.